# How to use backbone.js routes to trigger JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, html, url, backbone.js, hash

To start off, here's my little section of code that I'm trying to use to declare the routes -

```
<script>
    var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "test":                 "test",    // #test
  },

  test: hideone() {
    ...
  },

});
</script>
```

I'm trying to make it so that when someone reaches "www.website.com/index.html#test", it'll trigger the JavaScript function "hideone", which I have written out earlier in the document.

If it helps, here's "hideone" -

```
<script>

function hideone() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("one");
        elem.className = "hide";
}                       
</script>
```

I've never used backbone.js before, and I couldn't find documentation for my specific problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your router and you also need to call `Backbone.history.start`. From [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start):

> When all of your Routers have been created, and all of the routes are
>   set up properly, call Backbone.history.start() to begin monitoring
>   hashchange events, and dispatching routes.

So you need to add these 2 lines at the end of your script:

```
var router = new Workspace();
Backbone.history.start();
```

You also need to take into account what @w1zeman1p said about defining the test function. The call to `Backbone.Router.extend` receives an object where one of the properties is named `test` and whose value must be a function. You can either define it inline or assign it the hideOne function:

```
//opt1 - assign an existing function
test: hideOne 

//opt2 - inline
test: function(){
    //function code
}
```

I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qspwdrfm/1/) with the first approach.

**EDIT**

Make sure you include the scripts in the following order either on your head or before closing the body (As reference, you can check it on the fiddle by right clicking on the Result pane and selecting inspect):

```
<head>

  <!-- Include JS libraries before closing the head. You could also move them inside the body, right before the closing </body> -->   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <!-- Your code here in another <script> tag -->    
</head>
```

You can then include your JS in another `<script>` tag either before the closing `</head>` or before the closing `</body>`. (Please note that you don´t need to load the libraries from the urls above, I am just trying to clarify the order of the libraries)

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks so much. I'm having an issue though. It works perfectly in the fiddle, and I see how I can easily adapt this to fit my needs, but when I copy and paste it into my code(literally a straight copy+paste, to see if it worked at all), it doesn't work. The URL changed to "index.html#/test" which I need, but nothing happens. The dialogue box that pops up in the fiddle doesn't appear.

Comment: J.G Oh god, I can't believe I didn't try that before. I'm getting these two errors in console when I check them - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined backbone.js:219` and

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined index.html:261`

After some searching, I read up on underscore.js and how it's required for backbone.js. I've included underscore.js now, and the same error happens. I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you included underscore before backbone?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to do that. Fixed that, and it got rid of the first error(`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined backbone.js:219`), but not the second one. I don't know what could be causing the second error.

Comment: I tried to clarify how to load your libraries in the edit. You can also use the initial boilerplate [html document](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#getting-set-up) used in the book *Developing Backbone applications* as a guide.

Comment: Thanks! I've gotten it to work. Your answers were awesome, mate.

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side value of "test" in the routes object is a property whos value is a function. try this:

```
<script>
    var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "test": "test",
      },

      test: function() {
         var elem = document.getElementById("one");
         elem.className = "hide";
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have to type the function out again there?

I just tried this - 

`<script>
    var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        "test": "test",
      },

      test: function hideone() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("one");
        elem.className = "hide";
}            
    });
</script> `

and it didn't work. What did I do wrong this time? (apologies for my inability to catch on)

Comment: I think you need your url to be `www.website.com/index.html#/test` I think you dropped slash, also you can omit `hideOne` and define your function as an anonymous one but this is n't required

Comment: So that function thats being called is an instance method on the router. So you could either call `hideone` from inside the method set on router or just put the contents of hideone as the function body.